# Background Worker and SaveDialog

Tags: vb.net

I am very new with Background worker control. I have an existing project that builds file but throughout my project while building files I get the deadlock error.
I am trying to solve it by creating another project that will only consist out of the background worker. I will then merge them.

My problem is I don't know where it will be more effective for my background worker to be implemented and also the main problem is how can I use the SaveDialog with my background worker? I need to send a parameter to my background worker project telling it when my file is being build en when it is done.

This is where my file is being build:

```
  srOutputFile = New System.IO.StreamWriter(strFile, False) 'Create File

  For iSeqNo = 0 To iPrintSeqNo
    ' Loop through al the record types
    For Each oRecord As stFileRecord In pFileFormat
      If dsFile.Tables.Contains(oRecord.strRecordName) Then
        ' Loop through al the records
        For Each row As DataRow In dsFile.Tables(oRecord.strRecordName).Rows
          ' Check record id
          If oRecord.strRecordId.Length = 0 Then
            bMatched = True
          Else
            bMatched = (CInt(oRecord.strRecordId) = CInt(row.Item(1)))
          End If

          ' Match records
          If iSeqNo = CInt(row.Item(0)) And bMatched Then
            strRecord = ""
            ' Loop through al the fields
            For iLoop = 0 To UBound(oRecord.stField)
              ' Format field
              If oRecord.stField(iLoop).iFieldLength = -1 Then
                If strRecord.Length = 0 Then
                  strTmp = row.Item(iLoop + 1).ToString
                Else
                  strTmp = strDelimiter & row.Item(iLoop + 1).ToString
                End If
              ElseIf oRecord.stField(iLoop).eFieldType = enumFieldType.TYPE_VALUE Or _
                     oRecord.stField(iLoop).eFieldType = enumFieldType.TYPE_AMOUNT_CENT Then

                strTmp = row.Item(iLoop + 1).ToString.Replace(".", "").PadLeft(oRecord.stField(iLoop).iFieldLength, "0")
                strTmp = strTmp.Substring(strTmp.Length - oRecord.stField(iLoop).iFieldLength)
              Else
                strTmp = row.Item(iLoop + 1).ToString.PadRight(oRecord.stField(iLoop).iFieldLength, " ").Substring(0, oRecord.stField(iLoop).iFieldLength)
              End If

              If oRecord.stField(iLoop).iFieldLength > -1 And (bForceDelimiter) And strRecord.Length > 0 Then
                strTmp = strDelimiter & strTmp
              End If

              strRecord = strRecord & strTmp
            Next

            ' Final delimiter
            If (bForceDelimiter) Then
              strRecord = strRecord & strDelimiter
            End If

            srOutputFile.WriteLine(strRecord)
          End If
        Next
      End If
    Next
  Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
Private locker1 As ManualResetEvent = New System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(False)
Private locker2 As ManualResetEvent = New System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(False)
Dim bOpenFileOK As Boolean
Dim myOpenFile As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()

Private Sub FileOpener()
    While Not bTerminado
        If myOpenFile.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            bOpenFileOK = True
        Else
            bOpenFileOK = False
        End If

        locker2.Set()
        locker1.WaitOne()
    End While
End Sub

' Detonator of the action
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim tFileOp As Thread = New Thread(AddressOf FileOpener)
    tFileOp.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
    tFileOp.Start()

    ' Start BackgroundWorker
    BW1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub AsyncFunctionForBW(ByVal args As ArrayList)
    '[...]

    'Change options dinamically for the OpenFileDialog
    myOpenFile.Filter = ""
    myOpenFile.MultiSelect = True

    'Calling the FileDialog
    locker1.Set()
    locker2.WaitOne()
    locker1.Reset()
    locker2.Reset()

    If bOpenFileOK Then
        myStream = myOpenFile.OpenFile()

        '[...]
    End If
End Sub
```

It's a little bit complicated but it works.

`ManualResetEvents` interrupt the execution of code (if they are told to stop) when reached until you use `.Set()`. If you use `.WaitOne()` you set it in stop mode, so it will stop again when reached.

This code defines two `ManualResetEvents`. When you click the `Button1` starts the function `FileOpener()` in a new `Thread`, and then starts the `BackgroundWorker`. The `FileOpener()` function shows a `FileOpenDialog` and waits in the `locker1` so when you use `locker1.Set()` the function shows the file dialog.

As the `myOpenFile` is a "global" variable (as well as `bOpenFileOK`), once the user select the file (or not) you could detect the dialog result (`bOpenFileOK`) and the selected file.

Comment: Thanks for fast response. could you perhaps just explain briefly what you are doing since I am new with threads and background worker I want to understand fully what you are doing.

Comment: @G-Man Sure. I am editing my answer with more comments to clear whats code is doing.

Comment: @G-Man Done. If you don't understand anything just ask. Sorry if my explanation is not clear.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I am quite busy with something else at this moment but will give it a try as soon as I can.